# Zipkin traces in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, opentracing

Small question about the possibility to integrate Zipkin with Prometheus.

Currently, we have a working Zipkin instance fully ready, with its web UI. Zipkin is super cool, everything is fine.

We are able to have all micro services sending traces to Zipkin, and having Zipkin aggregating them.

We can also search the traces in the UI, etc, super cool.

On the other hand, we also have a very mature battle tested Prometheus Grafana, where container level metrics, application level metrics, and many other observations are already present in it.

Hence, currently, we have two places where we have to look at for production. Our everything in one place Prometheus, and this super cool Zipkin.

I was wondering, would it be possible to have Prometheus as the back end, or some kind of Prometheus consuming Zipkin data to display in Grafana, so we truly have all in one place please?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search for zipkin grafana you'll get this as one of the first results https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/zipkin/